# Get EmailId from UID?

Tags: dropbox-api

I got the following from fiddler whenever I try to login to dropbox.

```
[{"uid": 663175210, "sess_id": 272608865417613682242215474540606531660, "expires": 1495277184, "team_id": 2059286, "role": "work"}]
```

Notice that uid is being passed. I did some google and found that the uid is The Dropbox [user ID](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/P_Dropbox_Api_OAuth2Response_Uid.htm) of the authorized user.
Is there any way i can get the user email id (used to login to dropbox) using dropbox API, given that i have the corresponding uid?

Answer (score 0):

No, the Dropbox API doesn't offer a way to retrieve the user's email address by supplying the `uid`.

If the user has authorized your app on the API though, you can use the [/2/users/get_current_account](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#users-get_current_account) API call to get their account information, including email address.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am trying to develop a proxy server which restrict some users in an organisation to download the file in bussiness dropbox.
I am able to trap request for downloads in my proxy server with parameters like the UID, Session ID etc. I was hoping if I some how identify the user which the corresponding UID, check if he\she is allowed to download the document and then process the request accordingly. Any thoughts how I can achieve that?